# React-Bootstrap <FieldGroup> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a `FieldGroup` inside a Form and I came across this error:

**"Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid:** expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `CreateUser`.
    at invariant (invariant.js:44)

```
   import React, {Component} from 'react'
   import {Form, FormGroup , FormControl,AlertDismissable,Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap'
   import {FieldGroup} from 'react-bootstrap'
   class CreateUser extends Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

displayName: 'Create User'
render() {
    return (
            <Form horizontal className="loginForm">
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalUsername">
                    <FieldGroup>

                    </FieldGroup>
                </FormGroup>
            </Form>

    );
}
}  export default CreateUser;
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

FieldGroup is not a part of **react-bootstrap**

FieldGroup is a custom component. So you will have to create it and then only you can use it.

If you want to use group use **FormGroup** instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do add `FieldGroup` as function

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Form, FormGroup , FormControl, AlertDismissable, Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {FieldGroup} from 'react-bootstrap'
class CreateUser extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  displayName: 'Create User'
  render() {
    function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
      return (
        <FormGroup controlId={id}>
          <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl {...props} />
          {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
        </FormGroup>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Form horizontal className="loginForm">
          <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalUsername">
              <FieldGroup>
                id="formControlsText"
                type="text"
                label="Text"
                placeholder="Enter text"
          </FormGroup>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}  export default CreateUser;
```

For getting more detail you can go to this link [FieldGroup](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-controls).

Comment: your FieldGroup link is broken.